# Take videos present inside the videos icon in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, ios5

I'm doing a project in which it should take the videos present inside the videos icon present in the iPhone. Can any one help me by giving a link or something in doing that. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

it is not possible, because we cant acces one app from inside of another app

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`UIImagePickerController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) to pick the video.

Use the following code to show the picker.

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.delegate = self;
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
imagePicker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, nil];
[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
```

And to get the selected video URL, implement [UIImagePickerControllerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007069) protocol.

You will get the necessary values in the delegate method

`- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info`

through `info` dictionary.

Comment: No Aadhira its not UIImagePickerController, its used to take the contents from iphone photo library. But what i needed is to take the contents present inside the video icon in iPhone. These contents are videos downloaded from the itunes store. This is a feature in ios5 and later only